# How can we purchase multiple In App Auto renewing subscription of same product ID in iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

We have an app that supports multiple logins. We are providing "Pro" content of the app for the users who have purchased our subscription. However, In my understanding, we cannot buy the same auto-renewing subscription against an apple ID if it was already brought. It will be restored.

To be clear, A user named "USER A", buys a subscription "Pro-3-months" in our app and then logs off. Now "USER B" logs in and try to buy "Pro-3-months" in the same device, but it is always restored. Can we handle this as a new purchase?. I couldn't find any docs for the same scenario. However, I noticed that "Youtube" was able to provide the same functionality. How did they do it?.

[image]

Comment: You should track the original transaction id from the receipt against the user in your backend. When you see an original transaction id that is already associated with a user you can either transfer the subscription from user a to user b (user a loses the subscription benefits) or not activate the subscription benefits for user b

Comment: The other way is you do what YouTube does and have multiple subscription IAPs with the same price and description.  You can examine the receipt and again, check the original transaction against your backend database.  If there is already an active instance of subscription product "1" for a different user, set up a purchase for subscription product "2" and so on

Answer (score 0):

You wrote "Now "USER B" logs in and try to buy "Pro-3-months" in the same device"  -  actually your user B is using the same App Store ID as user A on that device and so the App Store restores the subscription.  If User A logged out of their App Store account and User B logged into their App Store account it would work.  So how do you do that?  One way is to convert to non-renewable subscriptions.  The App Store will allow the 'same' user to make multiple purchases.  But who is paying for each of those?